# Multiple routes in same controller for post and destroy action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm confused with routes, I am working on json data, admin/admins_controller.rb

Getting Routing Error `No route matches [POST] "/admin/adminsignup"*`

admin/admins_controller.rb

```
class Admin::AdminsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def adminlogin
    user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    if user&.valid_password?(params[:password]) 
      render json: user.as_json(only: :email,:first_name,:last_name,:phone,:authentication_token]), status: :created
    else
      head(:unauthorized)
    end
  end

  def adminsignup
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: {status: 'success', data:user}, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {status: 'error', message:'There was some error in registering the user.', data:user.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def logindestroy
    current_user&.authentication_token = nil
      if current_user.save
         head(:ok)
      else
         head(:unauthorized)
      end
  end   

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :phone)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 namespace :admin do
   post 'admins', to: 'admins#adminlogin'
   post 'admins', to: 'admins#adminsignup'
   destroy 'admins', to: 'admins#logindestroy'
 end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_token_authenticatable

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

1. How can I use different controllers for devise login, naming like admins_controller & users_controller?

Is is better way to do so? Please help.

Comment: ray pls need help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve, can be done by implementation provided [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin)

Edit your routes as per your controller defined.

Comment: like this =  post 'admins', to: 'admins#adminlogin'
                 post 'admins', to: 'admins#adminsignup'

Comment: Correct your routes as per https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, how you can provide `POST` verb to `adminsignup` route which just render new form (must be `GET`)